How to specify solver in logit regularized regression in statsmodels?
When building a simple Logit Regression with statsmodels with specify solver method = 'newton'
However, when I try to build regularized Logit model there is no opportunity to specify solver.
This is why statsmodels and sklearn l1 regularized models are different.
How can I specify newton method in fit_regulzrized in statsmodels?
import import statsmodels.api as sm
model = sm.Logit(y_train, x_train).fit(method = 'newton')
model_reg = sm.Logit(y_train, x_train).fit(method = 'l1').

GLM has coordinate descend as optimizer for elastic net/L1 penalization, but also no choice of alternative optimizer. Logit.fit_regularized uses an interior point algorithm that requires constrained optimization, but slsqp is the only choice for it of the scipy optimizers.

Aside, L1 penalization is only available in basic versions in statsmodels. The main problem is that inference is non-standard, and either not available or the available asymptotic distribution might not be a good approximation for the small (and medium sized) sample properties. Not having good inference removes most of the advantages of statsmodels compared to sklearn.
